# UISplitView : Need to hide left view for initial two screens

Tags: ipad, ios5, xcode4.2, uisplitviewcontroller

I have gone through various threads and tutorials but not able to find any solutions, so need to post the question. So the questions is :

- For initial three screens need to display only the detail view without any popover button at navigation bar in landscape. Now in third screen on button click i need to load the splitview with both left and right view.

I am aware of the methods which hides the left view panel in landscape mode. The only part i am worried id to load the splitview from 3rd screen .So need some suggestion to proceed further.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Matt Gemmel's](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad/) custom split view controller.